# unable to perform parallel execution in remote partition

Tags: java, spring-batch

Requirements:-
   define remote partition using spring batch

> Looks like all partitions are not performing parallel execution. 
>   As per my understanding, for example if gridSize  = 3 then all three partition should execute parallel to slave step(reader\process\writer) class.

```
    Configurations:-
        TaskExecutor:-
           corePoolSize = 3
           maxPoolSize  = 20
           queueCapacity = 100
       gridSize = 3
       chunkSize = 10
```

I have defined partitioner class which is returning executionContext with the same size of grid size.
   ExecutionContext={PART3= start=0, PART1=start=0, PART2= start=0}

```
ReaderClass:-

  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    log.info(stepExecution);
  }

  public Scope read(){
     --- some operations---
      return new Scope();
  }

  ProcessClass:-

   public Data process(Scope scope){
      -- some operations --
     return new Data(scope);
   } 

   WriterClass :-

    public void write(List<? extends Data> dataItemsSize){

      -- some operations --
     }
```

logs:-

```
            [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.389 [Container-28] Reader - beforeStep() reader: stepExecution=StepExecution: id=52175, version=1, name=MatchStep:PART2, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.452 [Container-49] Reader - beforeStep() reader: stepExecution=StepExecution: id=52173, version=1, name=MatchStep:PART3, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.455 [Container-28] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2855, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.455 [Container-28] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2841, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.456 [Container-28] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2851, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.456 [Container-28] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2863, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.476 [Container-30] Reader - beforeStep() reader: stepExecution=StepExecution: id=52171, version=1, name=MatchStep:PART1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.477 [Container-49] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2845, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.477 [Container-49] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2847, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.477 [Container-49] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2861, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.477 [Container-49] Reader - read() - END: scope=null
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.483 [Container-49] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2845, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.483 [Container-28] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2855, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2857, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2843, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2849, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2853, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2859, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2865, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.506 [Container-30] Reader - read() - END: scope=null
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.507 [Container-30] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2857, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.509 [Container-28] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2841, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.509 [Container-49] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2847, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.513 [Container-28] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2851, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.513 [Container-49] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART3, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2861, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.516 [Container-28] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART2, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2863, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.593 [Container-30] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2843, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.598 [Container-30] Process - process(): scope=Scope{partitionerId=PART1, openDate=Thu Jun 13 09:18:13 CDT 2019, execScopeId=2849, execId=1321, iTC=CX}
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.608 [Container-28] Writer - write(): dataItemsSize=4
        [INFO ] 2019-06-13 09:18:13.608 [Container-49] Writer - write(): dataItemsSize=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are using a `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` and according to your logs, partitions are executed in parallel by different threads (`Container-28`, `Container-30`, `Container-49`) as expected.

> Requirements:- define remote partition using spring batch

If you want to configure remote partitioning, you need to use the `MessageChannelPartitionHandler`. You can find an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. i was already using PartitonHandler interface for handling. should i change to MessageChannelPartitionHandler class?

Comment: And last point,  each Container will get same number of threads for execution. Means as corePoolSize  = 3, each container (28,30,49) will get each (3 min and max 10 ) thread for execution?    is it correct ?

Comment: That's correct. In regards to `should i change to MessageChannelPartitionHandler class?`, yes, that's the partition handler implementation to use for remote partitioning.